# Find the value of the integral $\int_0 ^2\int_0^2f(x+y)~dx~ dy$ where $f(t)$ denotes the greatest integer $\le t$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of the integral $$\int_0 ^2\int_0^2f(x+y)~dx~ dy$$ where $f(t)$ denotes the greatest integer $\le t$

**Solution Attempt:** Let $[y]$ represent the greater integer $\le y$ and $\{y\}$ the fractional part of $y$.

Let $x+y=t \implies dx = dt$. Hence, $\int_0 ^2\int_0^2f(x+y)~dx~ dy=\int_0 ^2\int_y^{y+2}f(t)~dt~ dy$.

$\int_y^{y+2}f(t)~dt= \int_y^{y+2}[t]dt$.

**Case $1$** **If $y$ is an integer**

$\int_y^{y+2}[t]dt = \int_y^{y+1}[t]dt +\int_{y+1}^{y+2}[t]dt = [y]+[y]+1=2[y]+1$.

**Case $2$ : If $y$ is not an integer**

$\int_y^{y+2}[t]dt = \int_y^{[y]+1 }[t]dt +\int_{[y]+1 }^{[y]+2}[t]dt+\int_{[y]+2}^ {y+2}[t]dt $.

$=[y] (1+\{y\})+([y]+1)+([y]+2)(\{y\})$

$=[y]+[y]\{y\}+[y]+1+[y]\{y\} + 2\{y\}$

$=2[y]+ 1+2[y]\{y\}+ 2\{y\}$

$=2y +1+2[y]\{y\}$

Could anyone please tell me if I have attempted this correctly?

Thank you for reading through!

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:** Use indicator functions. For set $A$, 
$$
{\bf 1}_{A}(t):=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}1;&\mbox{if }\,\,t\in A\\0;&\mbox{otherwise}\,.\end{array}\right.
$$

This means we can write,

> $$
> \int_0 ^2\int_0^2f(x+y)~dxdy\\{}={}\int_0 ^2\int_0^2\Big(1\cdot{\bf 1}_{[1, 2)}(x+y){}+{}2\cdot{\bf 1}_{[2, 3)}(x+y){}+{}3\cdot{\bf 1}_{[3, 4)}(x+y)\Big) ~dxdy\,.
> $$

Also, note that by the symmetry of the problem, for integer $j$,

> $$
> \int_0 ^2\int_0^2{\bf 1}_{[j, j+1)}(x+y)~dxdy{}={}\int_0 ^2\int_0^2{\bf 1}_{[0, j+1)}(x+y)~dxdy-\int_0 ^2\int_0^2{\bf 1}_{[0, j)}(x+y)~dxdy\,.
> $$

Finally, there are **triangles** in all of this.